# What are the pros and cons of Delayed Job vs RabbitMQ on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku, delayed-job, rabbitmq

I would like to write a `Node.js` UDP server on Heroku and plan to queue up the data to a Rails instance (dyno) for it to process? What are the pros and cons of using [Delayed Job](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) vs [RabbitMQ](http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2011/8/31/rabbitmq_add_on_now_available_on_heroku/)? Thanks, Chirag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are very hard to compare! RabbitMQ is a messaging system, while delayed_job is a database-backed task queue.

With RabbitMQ you can create a task queue, but that is just one of many use cases.
One could say that delayed_job is a very limited implementation of a task queue,, as the database is not suited for this kind of work.
(see e.g. http://www.rabbitmq.com/resources/RabbitMQ_Oxford_Geek_Night.pdf)
The database may work good enough for simple setups, but it is likely to eventually
fall apart.

If you want a task queue, I suggest you look for one that supports RabbitMQ.